# identify the rows with the lowest values in an array based on identical values in a column of that array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have an array of product data which includes code, description and cost. code is unique, cost is numeric and description is non-unique. Please see example. How can I select the cheapest of each product based on the description and price?

[image]

This is the result of using the MIN formula.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use VBa?

Comment: oh, and I hope not to use VBa!! :-)

Comment: I assume you're joking? If not, you really should have made that clear!

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output?  Would you like an added column where an indicator of cheapest product would appear for each qualifying line? (this is the easiest and has the least pitfalls)

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What you wrote does not match your screenshot; "code is unique, cost is numeric and description is non-unique", yet screenshot shows "Product" and "Cost".

Comment: @CharlieRB you are right and apologies for the omission, there should be an additional column "code" which represents the unique product code.

Comment: @Madball73 the expected result is open, however, ideally i was looking for a formula similar to VLOOKUP, where the formula sotres/presents either a value "lowest" or another value "not lowest" in the field/cell of each row. One can then using a filter, select "not lowest" and delete those records to be left with the "lowest" records.

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried as the question reads as if you have done nothing and want us to to do it all for you

Comment: that is debatable my friend, my question reads that I don't know how to solve the problem, I have thought about using formulae ( I have good knowledge of formulae) but I could find nothing to use that would lead me to the answer.

Comment: What is wrong with the 2 answers you've been given? Your OP never states no VBa, mine does exactly what you want? I mean, it may not be possible to do what you want with formula (neatly), and even if you do, it may not be scalable... May I ask why you don't want to use VBa (just out of curiosity)

Comment: On review, I see the subtle power of array formulae, which I never new before. I was able to apply this and use madball's answer as the solution. Your answer Dave required too much work in the background in order to implement, is your answer scalable too? I.e., what If I changed around the layout of my database/table/array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this array formula as a new "Lowest" column (adjusting range for your actual range), and copy down:

```
={IF(B2=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$9=A2,$B$2:$B$9)),"Y","")}
```

Comment: that NEARLY works, however, it only identifies the absolute lowest as opposed to identifying the lowest per Product, I've attached image to my question to illustrate the difference.

Comment: I forgot to tell you to put it as an array formula.

Comment: That works: I copied your formula, pasted it into the cell I needed and pressed CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to save the formula as an array formula. I was then able to extend the formula down across my table length and show all the product records with the cheapest prices. Much appreciated for your elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following VBa for you

```
    Dim hasRows As Boolean
    hasRows = True

    Dim currentRow As Integer
    currentRow = 2

    Dim previousProduct As String
    Dim currentProduct As String
    Dim rowOfProduct As Integer
    Dim lowPrice As Integer
    lowPrice = -999 ' dummy number
    Do While (hasRows)

        currentProduct = Range("A" & currentRow).Value

        If (previousProduct = "") Then
            previousProduct = currentProduct
        Else

            If (previousProduct <> currentProduct) Then
                lowPrice = -999 'dummy again
                Range("B" & rowOfProduct).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If

        End If

        If (Range("A" & currentRow).Value = "") Then
            hasRows = False
            Exit Do
        End If

        If (lowPrice = -999) Then
            lowPrice = Range("B" & currentRow).Value
            rowOfProduct = currentRow
        Else
            If Range("B" & currentRow).Value < lowPrice Then
                lowPrice = Range("B" & currentRow).Value
                rowOfProduct = currentRow
            End If
        End If

        previousProduct = currentProduct
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Loop
```

[image]